# Installing Nginx-auth-ldap on Debian

Tags: nginx, ldap, debian

I tried to install Nginx-auth-ldap on my Debian server, but I can't understand how to do it right. I have been looking on https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/wiki/How-to-install and tried the commands for Linux.

The thing I can't understand is

```
./configure --add-module=path_to_http_auth_ldap_module
make install
```

I don't have a folder called configure in the Nginx folder.

Please help me to understand how I will make that work.

Comment: I did solve it by using this method instead http://www.ducky-pond.com/posts/2012/Jul/installing-an-ldap-server-on-rpi/

Answer (score 1):

The key is one sentence from the linked page that you skipped. The whole instructions say:

> ```
> cd ~ && git clone https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap.git
> ```
>
> in nginx source folder
>
> ```
> ./configure --add-module=path_to_http_auth_ldap_module
> make install
> ```

"In nginx source folder" refers to a directory where you would have the source code of nginx. This means you are supposed to re-build nginx with the new module.

**What you should do**

- Download the nginx sources [1](http://nginx.org/en/download.html)
- Download the nginx-auth-ldap module
- Compile nginx with the module

However, I did not test this, so it is possible that you need additional libraries or sources like the ones for ldap...

Answer (score 0):

Don't install nginx through Debian's package manager. Instead, as jasperado suggested, you'll want to download nginx from source.

You can download the mainline version thus:

`wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.2.tar.gz && tar xzf nginx-1.9.2.tar.gz`

Before you build, you may want to make sure PCRE3 is installed on your system because ngx_http_rewrite_module requires it, and the installer will try to load this module.

When ready, you go into the nginx source directory and then you can do the whole configure and make thing. You might find [this article](http://www.allgoodbits.org/articles/view/29) helpful.

For example,

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-http_stub_status_module --add-module=$HOME/nginx-auth-ldap
make
sudo make install
```